# delete lines based on number of brackets?

Tags: linux, oracle, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to find a best way to replace some text in a file called listener.ora for oracle.  Mostly looking to replace "SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL" entry with something else... but i have couple of things that can go wrong here that i want to avoid...

First as you can see the entry can look like either Entry#1 or entry#2, First one has "SDU=" entry, while second one dont...do note the file will either have entry#1 or entry#2 and not both at the same time(at least not in our environment).

Second, i was thinking was to do a find of "SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL" and delete 6 or 7 lines from there, but as the entry varies (SDU= in one and not in other) i dont think its a good idea...

next thing, no matter what i can come up with i might find an environment that might have lets say 2 more lines in that entry then my script will break or cause other error....so it would be nice to have something that will work for these 2 entry and anything else that i might encounter in the future...one IMPORTANT thing i can think of is, no matter how many lines it have 6, 7, 9 or 9 it will always have a exact number for start and close brackets{ () }... starting from "(SID_LIST ="

I know what i want to replace with and i have that part worked out but struggling with how to delete the existing lines

```
### Entry #1

SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SDU = 32768)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/ORCL/11264)
    )
  )

## Entry #2

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/ORCL/11264)
    )
  )
```

The full listener.ora file typically look like this...

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS =
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (HOST = hostname)
          (PORT = 1578)
      )
    )
  )
 )

STARTUP_WAIT_TIME_LISTENER_ORCL = 0
CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER_ORCL = 10
TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER_ORCL = OFF
SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SDU = 32768)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /oracle/ORCL/11204)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will delete the content with matching parenthesis on the same line.  I'm not sure that's your problem though.

```
$ sed '/(.*)/d' file
```

will print

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
    )
  )

## Entry #2

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
    )
  )
```

UPDATE for the full file.

For this it's better to switch to `awk` for its power.

```
$ awk -v RS= -F"\n" '!/SID_LIST_LISTENER/{print} 
                      /SID_LIST_LISTENER/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                   if($i!~/\(.*\)/) print $i}' listener.ora
```

will only delete the matched parenthesis in the required context.

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS =
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (HOST = hostname)
          (PORT = 1578)
      )
    )
  )
 )
STARTUP_WAIT_TIME_LISTENER_ORCL = 0
CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER_ORCL = 10
TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER_ORCL = OFF
SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
    )
  )
```

UPDATE 2 to delete the full record

```
$ awk -F"\n" -v RS= '/SID_LIST_LISTENER/{sub("SID_LIST_LISTENER.*","")}1' listener.ora
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS =
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (HOST = hostname)
          (PORT = 1578)
      )
    )
  )
 )
STARTUP_WAIT_TIME_LISTENER_ORCL = 0
CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTENER_ORCL = 10
TRACE_LEVEL_LISTENER_ORCL = OFF
```

Comment: i dont think that will work, as it will delete all the other entries in the "LISTENER_ORCL" portion...

Comment: i think that will do the trick, but do you know by any chance how to get rid of the 5 lines afterwards ?? I think i can use sed to remove those 5 lines but again i might end up deleting wrong lines if i just say delete last 5 lines...

Comment: which 5 lines?  Do you want to remove the full record SID_LIST_LISTENER_ORCL?

Comment: UPDATE 2 works like a champ...this does the trick for me..THANK YOU VERY MUCH... now one last question...i am reading man page for AWK but having a hard time understanding what exactly your command is doing...could you please explain....also if you could tell me how can i make that change permanent in the file, instead of just on standard out..